# In Javascript array there are items, but when I pass an array to an MVC Controller, list/array is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ajax POST method 
to send objects stored in an array to Mvc Controller to save them to a database, but list in my controller is allways empty
while in Javascript there are items in an array.

here is my code with `Console.Log`.
My controller is called a `ProductController`, `ActionMethod` is called `Print`, so I written:
"`Product/Print`"

`Console.Log` showed this:
[image]

So there are 3 items!

```
 var print = function () {
        console.log(productList);
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: "Product/Print",
            traditional: true,
            data: { productList: JSON.stringify(productList) }
    });}
```

And when Method in my controller is called list is empty as image shows:
[image]

Obliviously something is wrong, and I don't know what, I'm trying to figure it out but It's kinda hard, because I thought everything is allright,
I'm new to javascript so probably this is not best approach?

Thanks guys

Cheers

Comment: Needs to be `data: JSON.stringify({ productList: productList });`

Comment: you are passing string and expecting it to be list of product list.

Comment: @StephenMuecke 
List is null now

Comment: Your also need to set `contentType: 'application/json'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending complex data over ajax, you need to send the json stringified version of the js object while specifying the `contentType` as "application/json". With the `Content-Type` header, the model binder will be able to read the data from the right place (in this case, the request body) and map to your parameter.

Also you do not need to specify the parameter name in your data(which will create a json string like `productList=yourArraySuff` and model binder won't be able to deserialize that to your parameter type). Just send the stringified version of your array.

This should work

```
var productList = [{ code: 'abc' }, { code: 'def' }];
var url = "Product/Print";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    contentType:"application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(productList)
}).done(function(res) {
    console.log('result from the call ',res);
}).fail(function(x, a, e) {
    alert(e);
});
```

If your js code is inside the razor view, you can also leverage the `Url.Action` helper method to generate the correct relative url to the action method.

```
var url =  "@Url.Action("Print","Product)";
```

Comment: You don't need to, but your can :)